# Change Hover to Onclick Toggle for Drop Down Menu

Tags: jquery, hover, click, submenu, menubar

I'm creating a website for my church and I have just completed the homepage. However, before moving on to other pages, I need to finalize the menu bar. Currently the menu is set to display a horizontal drop down when hovered over. I really desire to have this hover changed to a click function which I know can be solved through Javascript and/or JQuery. I've looked through several websites and cannot find something that fits my needs, especially since I want to keep my current CSS coding. I want to be able to click on the menu and have the sub-menu appear, and I would like the sub-menu to disappear if the user clicks on the same main menu item again or by clicking somewhere else on the screen.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!--Start Nav Menu-->
<nav>
<ul id="bar1">

    <!--Begin About Us-->
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
        <!--Begin drop down menu items-->
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><font color="#2b77a0">•</font> New to Nederland First AG</a>          
                <a href="#"><span style="margin-left:10px;"><font color="#2b77a0">•</font> Our History</span></a>
                <a href="#"><span style="margin-left:10px;"><font color="#2b77a0">•</font> Our Beliefs</span></a>
            </li>

        </ul>
        <!--End drop down menu items-->
    </li>
    <!--End About Us-->

            <!--Begin Ministries-->
    <li><a href="#">MINISTRIES</a>
        <!--Begin drop down menu items-->
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><font color="#2b77a0">•</font> Kids</a>          
                <a href="#"><span style="margin-left:10px;"><font color="#2b77a0">•</font> Youth</span></a>
                <a href="#"><span style="margin-left:10px;"><font color="#2b77a0">•</font> Women</span></a>
                <a href="#"><span style="margin-left:10px;"><font color="#2b77a0">•</font> Men</span></a>
            </li>

        </ul>
        <!--End drop down menu items-->
    </li>
    <!--End Ministries-->

                    <!--Begin Events-->
    <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a>
        <!--Begin drop down menu items-->
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><font color="#2b77a0">•</font> Latest News</a>          
                <a href="#"><span style="margin-left:10px;"><font color="#2b77a0">•</font> Monthly Calendar</span></a>
            </li>

        </ul>
        <!--End drop down menu items-->
    </li>
    <!--End Events-->

                        <!--Begin Listen Online-->
    <li><a href="#">LISTEN ONLINE</a>
        <!--Begin drop down menu items-->
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><font color="#2b77a0">•</font> Sermons</a>          
                <a href="#"><span style="margin-left:10px;"><font color="#2b77a0">•</font> Teachings</span></a>
                <a href="#"><span style="margin-left:10px;"><font color="#2b77a0">•</font> Archive</span></a>
            </li>

        </ul>
        <!--End drop down menu items-->
    </li>
    <!--End Listen Online-->
    <li><a href="pages/contact.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
    <li class="filler"></li>
</ul>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
nav {
position: relative;
width:960px;
z-index:9999;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding:0;
background-color:transparent;
text-align:justify;
margin-top:-10px;
font-size:0.1px;
}


#bar1 {


background-color:transparent;
padding:0;
text-align: justify;
overflow: hidden;
height:39px;
border-top: 1px solid #222222; border-bottom: 1px solid #90908e;
font-size:0.1px;
}


#bar1>li {
display:inline-block;
margin-top:8px;
height:100%;
}


#bar1>li>a {
font-family:'Oswald',Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
color:#464748;
text-decoration:none;

}
#bar1>li>a:hover,#bar1>li>a:active,#bar1>li:hover>a {
font-family:'Oswald',Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
color:#2b77a0;
text-decoration:none;

}

#bar1>li>ul>li {
border-top: none;
height:29px;
margin-top:8px;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
text-decoration:none;
background-color:transparent;
padding-top:7px;
}


#bar1>li:hover>ul>li{
display:block;
background-color:transparent;
}
#bar1>li>ul>li{
display:none;
text-decoration:none;
}

#bar1>li>ul>li>a
{
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
color:#90908e;
text-decoration:none;
}

#bar1>li>ul>li>a:hover, #bar1>li>ul>li>a:active, #bar1>li>ul>li:hover>a,
{
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:black;
}

li {
list-style-type:none;
}

.filler 
{
width:100%;
display:block;
height:0px;
}
```

So in short again, I'm just looking for a way either through JS or JQuery to replace the hover into a click function. Thanks for any help and advice.

And here is my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Broli/ms74wnry/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this jQuery code:

```
$("#bar1").on("click","li", function(){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $("#bar1 > li").each(function(){//close all opened sub-menu
        $(this).find("ul li").css("display", "none");
        $(this).find("ul li").css("text-decoration","none");
    });
    $(this).find("ul li").css("display", "block");
    $(this).find("ul li").css("background-color","transparent");
});
$('html').click(function() {
    $("#bar1 > li").each(function(){//close all opened sub-menu
        $(this).find("ul li").css("display", "none");
        $(this).find("ul li").css("text-decoration","none");
    });
});
```

I use `event.stopPropagation` because..

> If a click event propagates to the  element, hide the menus. If
>   the click event originated from inside #bar, stop that event so it
>   will never reach the  element, thus only clicks outside of #bar
>   will hide the menus.

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ms74wnry/2/)..

Comment: Thank you for your response, I really appreciate it. I looked at your Fiddle, and I tried implementing into my own code. However, both the Fiddle and the implementation I attempted did not do anything. The only thing I saw that happened was that it took away the hover, but when I tried to click on the main menu items, the sub-menus did not appear. Is there something else that needs to be changed in my coding in order for your codes to work?

Comment: I'm utilizing JQuery already for some animation purposes, so I already have a link to JQuery 2.11.1 from Googleapis, and I also have an external file linked to JQuery 1.11.0. Perhaps one of these is conflicting with one another? I'm unsure, but I will check anyway because your code still is not working for me currently.

Comment: Maybe.. I think you only need one of those and IMHO just keep using the latest version..

Comment: Sadly, I'm still having issues with it not working. I tried taking away JQuery 1.11.0 and kept 2.1.1, but my animations stopped working. Even leaving 1.11.0 and inputting your code again, I still do not see anything happening. I really appreciate your help, but it seems that it just won't work for some reason.

Comment: Well, that's weird.. Because you see in my fiddle it works fine.. Hope you can find the issue..

Comment: Okay, I was finally able to get your code to work! All I had to do was add "jQuery(window).load(function()" to the beginning of your code, and then I just needed to define the event handler. I initially did not know how to do that, but it was a lot easier than I thought. Thank you so much for your help! I don't think I could have figured this out on my own, and I really appreciate the time you spent to help me.

Comment: Ups. My bad then, I should have told you about the load function. Glad it works.